# Salesforce Error - Figuring the Number of Weekdays between 2 dates

Tags: formula

I have two fields - Project Created Date and Onboarding Completed Date and I am trying to figure out how many weekdays are between the 2 dates.

Formula

```
(5 * ( FLOOR( ( Project__c.Onboarding_Completed_Date__c( 1900, 1, 8) ) / 7 ) ) + MIN( 5, MOD( Project__c.Onboarding_Completed_Date__c( 1900, 1, 8), 7 ) ) )
-
DATEVALUE (expression) (5 *  (FLOOR( ( CUST_CREATED_DATE( 1900, 1, 8) ) / 7 ) ) + MIN( 5, MOD( CUST_CREATED_DATE( 1900, 1, 8), 7 ) ) )
```

Getting the following error

> Error when encoding row-level formula: Syntax error. Extra '('

But I am not seeing an extra "("

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've noticed by now, but you have an extra "DATEVALUE (expression)" in your formula.